# How can I graph this inequality on the x-y plane?

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I'd like to graph the following inequality on the x-y plane:

$$
P(y): (\forall x\in [0,y))\left(\frac{x - \epsilon(1+a)}{a} \leq y \leq \frac{x + \epsilon(1+a)}{a}\right)
$$

This is the set of points  $(x,y)$ where $\frac{x - \epsilon(1+a)}{a} \leq y \leq \frac{x + \epsilon(1+a)}{a}$ for all $0 \leq x < y$. That is, for a point to be in the set, it must satisfy the inequality, *and* all points to its "left" with the same y-value must also satisfy the inequality.

$\epsilon \in (0,1]$ and $a \in (0,1]$ are both pre-defined constants.

Ideally, the plot would use multiples or combinations of $a$ or $\epsilon$ rather than numerical axis labels, but if I have to plug in values for $a$ and $\epsilon$ to plot this in Mathematica that would be okay (as an aside, if anyone knows an application that *can* plot this purely symbolically, please let me know!).

Comment: Please include in your question the code that you already have tried for this purpose.  Doing so will increase your chances of obtaining a useful response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[RegionPlot[
  (x - e (1 + a))/a <= y <= (x + e (1 + a))/a && 0 <= x <= y && 
   y <= e (1 + a),
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 60],
 {{e, .5}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{a, .5}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is close except I think the constraints are not quite right. For example, as you can see at the top of the plot you posted, there is a shaded region where, for the same $y$, points to its left are not shaded. Those points should be excluded. Also $0 < a \leq 1$ and $0 < e \leq 1$. I think this works: ``Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[(x - e (1 + a))/a <= y <= (x + e (1 + a))/a && 
   0 <= x <= y && y <= e (1 + a), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 60], {e, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {a, 0.01, 
  1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]``

Comment: @sundance updated, but i did not see $y <= e (1 + a)$ in your original post.

Comment: Right, it wasn't there, it's just a necessary condition to make sure the inequality is satisfied for a given $y$ *for all* $x$.